# Computing midway coordinates of nodes and joins in TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a part of what I want to do. Please keep in mind, that in the original the width of the boxes/nodes is variable, and the length of chain B and C ist not everytime the same.

```
% ---    ---     ---
% |A|    |B|     |C|
% ---    ---     ---
%  |      |  ---  |
%  |      |--|X|--|
%  |      |  ---  |
%  |     ---     ---
%  |     |b|     |c|
%  |     ---     ---
%  |      |       |
%  |      |  ---  |
%  ----------|E|---    
%            ---
```

I found some TiKz examples on the web and in the docu itself. When reading them I understand them but I am not able to transfere that to my own code. One of my problems is how to compute the correct coordinates for box-`X`. There should be some kind of `(B.x+.5,B.y+.5)`.
And going some steps more I have a seamless problem when I would try to draw the lines e.g. from `X` to the middle of the line between `B` and `b`.
I am sure I don'T really udnerstand all details of the `calc` package. And I am even not sure if it is the right selection for my needs. Maybe another coordinate system whould be better?

```
\documentclass{article}
% TiKz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        every node/.style={
            draw,
            align=center},
        every join/.style=->
    ]
    \node (A) {A};

    {[start chain=B going below,
      every node/.append style=join]
        \node (B) [on chain,right=of A] {B};
        \node [on chain] {b};
    }

    {[start chain=C going below,
      every node/.append style=join]
        \node (C) [on chain,right=of B] {C};
        \node [on chain] {c};
    }

    % from here I am out of solutions!
    \node (X) at ($(B-1)!0.5!(C-1)$) {X};

    \node (E) at ($(B-2)!0.5!(C-2)$) {E};

    \draw [->] (A) |- (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After naming the lower-case nodes, the calculations can be nested together as shown below. I added `\vphantom{b}` to the text of the `c` node, so it's the same height as its neighbor.

Connecting the various nodes can be done using the `|-` (vertical first, then horizontal) and `-|` (horizontal first, then vertical) path specifiers. It was unclear how you wanted arrows handled for these connections, but this is easily adjusted with the `\draw` command options.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw},every join/.style=->]
  \node (A) {A};
  {[start chain=B going below,every node/.append style=join]
    \node (B) [on chain,right=of A] {B};
    \node (b) [on chain] {b};
  }
  {[start chain=C going below,every node/.append style=join]
    \node (C) [on chain,right=of B] {C};
    \node (c) [on chain] {c\vphantom{b}};
  }
  \node (X) at ($($(B)!0.5!(C)$)!0.5!($(b)!0.5!(c)$)$) {X};
  \node (E) at ($($(B)!0.5!(C)$)-(0,2.5)$) {E};
  \draw [->] (A) |- (E);
  \draw (X) -| (c)
        (X) -| (b)
        (b) |- (E)
        (c) |- (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is no need to name the sub-nodes because they are named automaticly in a chain. e.g. `B-1, B-2, ...`

Comment: @buhtz yep, that's totally possible... I'm new to the `chains` library. :-)

Comment: Can I use the calculation (`X`) to specify a `\coordinate`? I can't get this workin with `\coordinate[$...$] (cX)`

Comment: @buhtz yes, similar to `\node (<name>) at (<location>);`, you can have `\coordinate (<name>) at (<location>);` where `<location>` might involve some calculations depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your image with following code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,chains,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, align=center},
     arrow/.style = -{Straight Barb[]},
      start chain = going right,
      node distance = 18mm and 9mm
                        ]
\node (A) [on chain] {A};
\node (B) [on chain] {B};
\node (C) [on chain] {C};
%
\node (b) [below=of B] {b};
\node (c) [below=of C] {c};
%
    \coordinate[below=9mm of B]  (x');
\node (X) [at={($(x')!0.5!(x'-|C)$)}]   {X};
\node (E) [below=of X]                  {E};
%
\path[arrow]    (B)      edge (b)  (C) edge (c)
                (B |- X) edge (X)  (C |- X) edge (X)
                (b)      edge (b |- E);
\draw[arrow]    (A) |- (E);   
\draw[arrow]    (c) |- (E);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, in code I didn't use macro `join` from `chains` package. Instead it I rather explicit draw paths between nodes, since this is less demanding, use less code and code structure is clear  (as with macro `join`).

On chain is only firs row of nodes (`A`, `B` and `C`), other are positioned with respect to nodes above them. Exception is node X, for which I define auxiliary coordinate  `c'`.

**Upgrade:** If you like to stick with macro `join` (for any cost ... :-)), see, if the code below fulfill your demad

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, many, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,chains,positioning}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={draw, on chain},
          start chain=going below,
     arrow/.style = -{Straight Barb[]},
every join/.style = {arrow},
reset/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}
                        ]
\node (A) {A};
\node (B) [right=of A] {B};
\node (b) [join] {b};
%
\node (C) [right=of B] {C};
\node (c) [join] {c\vphantom{b}};
%
\node (X) [below=0.5 of $(B)!0.5!(C)$]  {X};
\node (E) [below=of X]                  {E};
%
\draw [arrow]   (A) |- (E);
\draw [arrow]   (X) -| (c)  (X) -| (b)
                (b) |- (E)  (c) |- (E);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

Code is derived from code in Paul Gessler answer, however from it is "very significantly" different:

- position of node "X" is defined simpler (as below of middle point between nodes "B" and C")
- parameter `on chain` is part of style `every node`, consequently it is not necessary anymore define this in picture
- nodes, where the macro `join` can be exploited, has added this option locally

Result: concise and clean code ...

Comment: @buhtz, see upgrade of my answer. By the way, in one of your coments, you mention: "*I think there is no need to name the sub-nodes because they are named automatically in a chain. e.g. B-1, B-2, ...*". Can you elaborate this? Where I can found more information about this? So far my tests of this not confirm your statement.

Comment: @buhtz, I figured out the names of nodes in chain! Thank you for info.